# A simple differential equation question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$dy/dx=(xy+2x)/(y-1+x^2)$How to solve this equation?

Comment: What makes you think this equation can be solved ?

Comment: Treating $y$ as the independent variable, you can obtain a Bernoulli equation from this: $$\frac {dx (y)}{dy}-\frac {x (y)}{y+2}=\frac {y-1}{y+2}\cdot \frac {1}{x (y)} $$ This can then be converted into a linear ODE.

Comment: Thank you!! It is a nice way to solve this problem!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Hint***

You can try integrating factor to make it exact 
$$  \frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {(xy+2x)}{(y-1+x^2)}$$
$$dy(y-1+x^2)-dx(xy+2x)=0$$
$$-x(y+2)dx +(y-1+x^2)dy=0$$
$$Pdx+Qdy=0$$
The formula for integrating factor depending only on y is
$$\frac {d\mu}{\mu dy}=-\frac 1P(\partial_y P-\partial_x Q)$$
Factor integrating is 
$$  \frac {d\mu}{\mu dy}=-\frac 3 {y+2}$$
$$  \ln|\mu|=-\int \frac 3 {y+2}dy$$

---

***Another view..***

Or consider simply $x$ as a function
$$y'=\frac {(xy+2x)}{(y-1+x^2)}$$
$${(y-1+x^2)}=x'x{(y+2)}$$
$${(y-1+x^2)}=\frac 12(x^2)'{(y+2)}$$
Then simply substitute $z=x^2$

$${(y-1+z)}=\frac 12z'{(y+2)}$$
$$z'-\frac {2z}{y+2}=2\frac {(y-1)}{(y+2)}$$
It's easy to solve since its a linear ode

Comment: Woo !thank you! That is so cool

Comment: Well what is done with this integrating factor? thanks, i mean how the solution is given? I know the method that projectilemotion mentions in comment, is it same?

Comment: Well its exact then

Comment: @Isham I was confused because you havent written in explicit form, so how could you arrive at expression of integrating factor from the line three, thanks

Comment: @KingTut I added some lines for the integrating factor to get exactness

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I dont know what it means, I havent covered much maths till now.

Comment: @KingTut its a classical method that helps solve lots of differental equations. Type google for differential equation and exactness

Comment: @KingTut take a look at Paul's course on exactness http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Exact.aspx